# getting the iterator position in a string in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, g++

I am using `gdb` and I'd like to know in which point of a `std::string`  the iterator I am inspecting is.

E.G. Is `it` at 2nd or 3rd position of the string?

I tried to call `std::distance` but it doesn't work.

```
const std:string &cs;
std::string::const_iterator it;

(gdb) call std::distance(cs.begin(), it);
No Symbol "distance" in namespace "std"
```

Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: What does `print *it` show?

Comment: (const char &) @0x6296c0: 123 '{'

Comment: You can try `&*it - &*cs.begin()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compiled with `g++` or `clang++` you can do this:

```
p it._M_current - cs.begin()._M_current
```

For other compilers you can find out the internal layout by typing

```
p it.<TAB><TAB>
```

and reverse engineering where the data is kept.

Answer (score 4):

`std::distance` is templated function and it's template parameters are deduced in C++ code but gdb fails to do it and you have to call `std::distance` with explicit template parameter in gdb.

Here is example of how to do it with `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };

    auto distance = std::distance(v.begin(), v.end());

    std::cout << distance << '\n';
}
```

Sample gdb session (use Tab completion to autocomplete actual iterator type):

```
:$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40096d: file t.cpp, line 7.
Starting program: /home/asemenov/git-cpp/programs/ecpmd/a.out 
Trying host libthread_db library: /home/asemenov/libthread_db.so.1.
td_ta_new failed: application not linked with libthread
thread_db_load_search returning 0

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.cpp:7
7       std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };
(gdb) n
9       auto distance = std::distance(v.begin(), v.end());
(gdb) call 'std::distance<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)'(v.begin(), v.end())
$1 = 3
(gdb)
```

Comment: Hi! That help me out! Nice explanation!